# How can I get all the session that start with the same word?

Tags: php, html

I have problem with building a cart. 
How can I get all the sessions that starts with the same word?

Comment: Really need more information - I do not vote down - but edit question please because someone will and there is simply not enough information.  What database are you using - it is tagged as php and html - so I guess that is the languages.  A session is a particular php way of making values available globally - but I do not think that is what you mean - it sounds like you want to sort your products in some way - to help you we need a fuller explanation and some sample code / data - example of desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$start = 'startingword';
$new_session = array();
foreach($_SESSION as $index=>$value) {

    $temp = explode(' ', $index, 2);
    if($temp[0] == $start) {
        $new_session[$index] = $value;
    }
}
```

If the starting word is session value and not index, then,

```
foreach($_SESSION as $index=>$value) {

    $temp = explode(' ', $value, 2);
    if($temp[0] == $start) {
        $new_session[$index] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with a loop for the session name

foreach($_SESSION as $string {
    echo  'Session name is: ' . $string . '
';
}

This would echo all session names
Then modify code to include substr() to check if word matches - I can not really give code for this because it depends on if it is always the same word in which case a simple substr() or variable length in which case do a strlen("word") first or a character separator like - or _ in which case you can do strpos(); to find the length